# typeof call for a function with the name passed as a string

Tags: javascript, typeof

I am trying to create a generic click event function for all the fields on a page which primarily checks for the target being blank or containing a user-entered value. However, I would like for this generic function to check for existence of a more specific function and, if one is found, to allow it to handle the validation of the target value.
example:

```
function genValueCheck(event) {
   var af = event.target.id+'_checkValue';
   if (typeof af == 'function') runFunction(af,[event]); // logic specific to this field
   else { 
      // logic for checking for blanks, etc which applies to all fields
   }
}
```

However, typeof returns 'string' in the above example, as it should since it is checking for the typeof 'af', and not what 'af' contains, i.e. the name of a function.

Is what I am attempting to do possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `af` *is* a string. If your function exists in the global scope, use `window[af]`. This should work for you:

```
function genValueCheck(event) {
   var af = event.target.id+'_checkValue';
   if (typeof window[af] == 'function') runFunction(af,[event]); // logic specific to this field
   else { 
      // logic for checking for blanks, etc which applies to all fields
   }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VHjT9/)

Answer (score 2):

Create an object that contains all your functions so you don't pollute the global namespace, then use bracket notation to retrieve it:

```
var validators = {};
validators.checker1 = function() { ... };

function genValueCheck(event) {
    var af = event.target.id+'_checkValue';
    if (typeof validators[af] == 'function') {
        validators[af](event); // logic specific to this field
    } else { 
    // logic for checking for blanks, etc which applies to all fields
    }
}
```